# Show 401 unauthorized error from custom basic authentication wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am using custom basic authentication in wcf service with asp.net(c#). I want to give custom error of unauthorized when set wrong username or password.

overview of code like:

```
 public class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor : RequestInterceptor
    {

        MembershipProvider provider;
        string realm;

        public BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(MembershipProvider provider, string realm)
            : base(false)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.realm = realm;
        }

        protected string Realm
        {
            get { return realm; }
        }

        protected MembershipProvider Provider
        {
            get { return provider; }
        }

 public override void ProcessRequest(ref RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)requestContext.RequestMessage.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

if (//wrong password)
                    {

                        try
                        {


                            string errorHtml = "<html><HEAD><TITLE>Request Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>" +
            "<H1>Error processing request</H1><P>{0}</P></BODY></html>";
                            XElement response = XElement.Load(new StringReader(
                                string.Format(errorHtml, "Missing or invalid user key (supply via the Authorization header)")));

                            Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null,response);
                            HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };

                            responseProperty.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                            String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));

                            reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = responseProperty;
                            requestContext.Reply(reply);
                            requestContext = null;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex.InnerException;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

In this code not giving error and response body set proper but header, status code,etc.
response gives 200 OK. but want to 401-unauthorized.

can any one help how to set 401 error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it my self by updating message second parameter(string action) null to "action" and it's working fine.

```
Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null,response);

updated

Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "action" ,response);
```

and get response description in HTML format add one line in my code

```
responseProperty.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
```